# Div inside iframe not entirely visible because of iframe margins

Tags: html, css, iframe, internet-explorer-8

I have a div inside an iframe. My problem is that when the div opens, its content is not displayed entirely because of the width limitations of the iframe. I tried playing with the z-index and did set a higher z-index value for the div inside iframe, with no success. Any advice much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have some code for us to look at?

Answer (score 1):

You can't overflow contents out of the boundary of an `iframe`. Thus the `overflow` and `z-index` properties can't be used to let some element flow out an `iframe`.

You need to either increase the width of the frame or not use an `iframe` at all; for example loading the contents via AJAX and inserting them into another element of your document.

Answer (score 1):

You could auto-resize the iframe when the contents are loaded:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function autoResize(id){
    var height = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight;
    var width = document.getElementById(id).contentWindow.document.body.scrollWidth;

    document.getElementById(id).height= (height) + "px";
    document.getElementById(id).width= (width) + "px";
  }
</script>

<iframe src="yourpage.html" id="yourframe" onLoad="autoResize('yourframe');"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use absolute position of div?
Something like:

```
.div-overlay {
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:100px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be because of frame body margin use `margin:0` in iframe

```
html,body {margin:0px; padding:0px}   //use this in  iframe css
```